# Gradle Multi project build prefixed jar and maven publication

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle multi project build with the following layout:

```
    Root
     +---ProjectA
     +---ProjectB
     +---ProjectC
     +    ...
```

The jars which will be produced by the subprojects need to be prefixed. e.g. PREFIX-ProjectA.jar. That's working.

How can I tell maven-publish task that it searches for "PREFIX-ProjectA.jar"? Currently it searches for "ProjectA.jar"

My publishing section looks like this:

```
    task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
        baseName 'PREFIX-' + project.name
        from sourceSets.main.allJava
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {

                artifactId 'PREFIX-' + project.name

                from components.java

                artifact sourceJar {
                    classifier "sources"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody runs in the same issue here's my solution:

```
    /**
     * Creates a jar containing all sources
     */
    task jarSources(type: Jar) {
        baseName = 'PREFIX-' + project.name
        from sourceSets.main.allJava
        classifier = 'sources'
    }

    /**
     * Creates the jar file
     */
    task jarExecutable(type: Jar) {
        baseName = 'PREFIX-' + project.name
        from sourceSets.main.output
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                artifactId 'PREFIX-' + project.name

                artifact jarExecutable

                artifact jarSources

                //....
            }
        }   
    }
```